# R) Counts.csv.gz file to Seurat object

Tags: r, seurat

I usually import filtered feature bc matrix including `barcodes.tsv.gz`, `features.tsv.gz`, and `matrix.mtx.gz` files to R environment by `Read10X` function, and convert the data to Seurat object by `CreateSeuratObject` function.

However, I found out that some publicly available processed `scRNA-seq data` was shared only in the format of `counts.csv.gz` file.
So, I tried to convert the `counts.csv.gz` files to Seurat object via following commands;

> countsData<-read.delim(file = "~path/TUMOR1_counts.csv.gz", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
> Tumor2 <- CreateSeuratObject(counts = countsData, project = "Tumor2", min.cells = 3, min.features = 200)

However, the following error occured.

> Error in CreateAssayObject(counts = counts, min.cells = min.cells, min.features = min.features) :
> No feature names (rownames) names present in the input matrix

Here is the counts.csv file that looks like this.
How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At first, count matrix as an input for `CreateSeuratObject()` should have the cells in column and features in row. It seems like that you should use t() to convert your imported counts with the rownames.

I recommend you do like this:

```
countsData <- read.csv(file = "~path/TUMOR1_counts.csv", header = TRUE, row.names = 1)
Tumor2 <- CreateSeuratObject(counts = t(countsData), project = "Tumor2", min.cells = 3, min.features = 200)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I tried the following command you recommended (countsData <- read.csv(file = "~path/TUMOR1_counts.csv", header = TRUE, row.names = 1), the following error occured; Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed.

Comment: And.. when I only converted the imported counts via t(), I got this error; "Error in CreateAssayObject(counts = counts, min.cells = min.cells, min.features = min.features) : 
  No cell names (colnames) names present in the input matrix"

Comment: @Juhee I think the dataset have duplicated cell names. Try the code without ```row.names=1```.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have empty cells. You should fill them with zeros.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33734976)